# logging nginx events from a docker container managed by kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, fluentd, filebeat

Currently, to my understanding, kubernetes offers no logging solutions on it's own and it also does not allow one to specify the logging driver when using docker as the container technology due to scope encapsulation concerns.

This leaves folks with the ugly solution of tailing json logs from shared volumes using either fluentd, filebeat, or some other file tailing demon, parsing these, then sending them to the desired storage backend.

My question is, is there any repo or public knowledge config store for this type of scenario for people that have gone through this before? My use case would involve tailing the logs of a nginx docker image and writing out the fluentd/grok pattern myself seems really painful, plus i wouldn't want to struggle on an issue already solved by someone else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We tried [logdna](https://logdna.com/) and the integration with k8s is pretty solid. Most of the time I just tail the log of some container using kubectl logs -f [CONTAINER_ID]. I'm guessing you're looking for a persistent approach.

Comment: that's correct... we're aiming for a unified log solution for all containers managed by k8s